# Expected number of coin tosses until same consecutive output

Tags: probability, expected-value

I looked a lot for the answer to this question online, with no success.

The coin used is not fair, and has: $\displaystyle P( H) =\frac{2}{3}$. $\displaystyle P( T) =\frac{1}{3}$.

I wrote a solution that makes sense to me, but the overall answer is kinda weird, so I would love if anyone could solve/review my answer.

My solution:

Let $\displaystyle W=number\ of\ tosses\ until\ same\ consecutive\ output\ ( including)$.

Let's look at the following complementary events:

$\displaystyle HH,\ HT,\ TT,\ TH$.

From Total Law of Examplaction:

$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
E[ W] =P( HH) \cdotp E[ W|HH] +P( TT) \cdotp E[ W|TT] +P( HT) \cdotp E[ W|HT] +P( TH) \cdotp E[ W|TH]\\
=\frac{4}{9} \cdotp 2+\frac{1}{9} \cdotp 2+\frac{2}{9} \cdotp ( 2+E[ W]) +\frac{2}{9} \cdotp ( 2+E[ W])\\
=2+\frac{4}{9} \cdotp E[ W]\\
\Longrightarrow \\
\frac{5}{9} E[ W] =2\\
E[ W] =\frac{18}{5}
\end{array}$

Which rounds up to $\displaystyle 4$.

Is the logic behind even correct? How am I not getting an integer as anwer?

Comment: Are you talking about paths like $THTHH$ or $HTHTHTT$?   But in that case:  the first toss is whatever it, after that matching the prior toss is a $50-50$ affair, so (given the first toss) the expected number is $2$, making the final answer $3$ (because you have to count the first toss).

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835458/expected-value-of-two-successive-heads-or-tails-stuck-on-computation) is a duplicate which addresses the same question for a (possibly) weighted coin.

Comment: Yes, those would be valid examples. I kind of understand the idea that matching the first toss is a $50-50$ affair, even if in this case the prob. is not $1/2$. But I don't understand from there why given the first toss the expected number is $2$. Also, in this case, the answer is $3$, so where is the mistake in my answer?

Comment: i can't follow your calculation.  Let $E_1$ be the expectation after the first toss. This is the same whether you have tossed $H$ or $T$ (the calculation is very slightly harder for a weighted coin).  Then consider the possible outcomes of the second toss we see that $E_1=\frac 12\times 1 + \frac 12\times (E_1+1)\implies 2E_1=2+E_1\implies E_1=2$.

Comment: Ah, in your calculation you incorrectly claim, e.g., that $E[W\,|\,HT]=2+E[W]$.  The recursion only works for $E_1$, not for $E$ (to use my notation).  The first toss is special, because it is the only one which can not end the game.

Comment: Should add:  there is absolutely no reason to expect an integer as an answer (though it happens to be an integer).  The expected value for a single toss of a fair die is $3.5$ despite the fact that the outcome of the toss has got to be an integer.

Comment: Should stress:  my computations are for a fair coin.  If you want to consider a biased coin, you need to introduce $E_H$ and $E_T$ to reflect the results of the prior toss.  I'll post a solution below.

Comment: Do you mean "until first $HH$ or $TT$"?

Comment: "$\frac{18}{5}$  ... which rounds up to $4$" That's a pretty wild (and uncalled for) rounding.

Answer (score 1):

(N.B.  [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835458/expected-value-of-two-successive-heads-or-tails-stuck-on-computation) is a duplicate, but I think the simple recursive argument presented here is worth recording).

Suppose the coin comes up $H$ with probability $p$.

Let $E_H$ (resp. $E_T$) denote the expected number of tosses to get a match, given that the prior toss was $H$ (resp. $T$).

Then we see that $$E_H=p\times 1 +(1-p)\times (E_T+1)\quad \& \quad E_T=(1-p)\times 1+p\times (1+E_H)$$

Which yields $$E_H=\frac {2-p}{p^2-p+1}\quad \&\quad E_T=\frac {p+1}{p^2-p+1}$$

Letting $E$ be the expectation from the start (prior to the first toss) we see that $$E=p\times (E_H+1)+(1-p)\times (E_T+1)$$

and combining the results completes the computation:  $$E=\frac 3{p^2-p+1}-1$$

Sanity check:  Note that this correctly yields $3$ when $p=\frac 12$

When $p=\frac 23$ as in your specific question, we get $E=\frac {20}7$.  As mentioned in the comments, there is no reason to expect the answer to be an integer.